# "Whomsoever" as a subject

Tags: grammar, pronouns

In the big-budget game *Warcraft III*, the following is written on a pedestal:

> Whomsoever takes up this blade shall wield power eternal.

Is it correct to use *whomsoever* as a subject, as in this sentence?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As this is the subject of the sentence, it should be *whosoever*. *Whomsoever* is the objective case.